# 'Mi' is not a subtype of type 'IF' with dart2js

Tags: dart, dart2js

I'm facing an issue with dart2js since today, dart2js go to the end without any error, but when i launch my webapp on a browser (Chrome) the console send this error "Uncaught type 'Mi' is not a subtype of type 'IF' "
But when running on Dartium, there is no bug. I'm not really into JavaScript, so i don't know how to investigate further.

My app is deployed there :
    5.231.68.247/comprachicos/index.html 
And the page with the bug is :
    5.231.68.247/comprachicos/jeu.html

My sources are on Github here :
    https://github.com/eagleofdeath13/Comprachicos/tree/master/web

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I'm running it in Dartium it does cause an exception too.

In your jeu.html you have

```
<input id="nextPageButton" type="button"/>
```

And in your main.dart you have:

```
ButtonElement b = querySelector("#nextPageButton");
```

And so the error message in Dart is:

```
Exception: type 'InputElement' is not a subtype of type 'ButtonElement' of 'b'.
```

Either use a `button`-tag in your html or an `InputElement` in your `main.dart` to fix this issue.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem :)
But error was not showing on my Dartium.